# How to keep recording the height of an element using javascript even without reloading the page

Tags: javascript, html

In my javascript code I am taking the width of body and checking if the width of the body is at specific value then add or remove the onclick function from the elements but when i decrease/increase the size of the page the onclick function does not add/remove respectively according to the condition i just wanted to keep record of the width of the body so that without reloading the page the onclick function gets add/remove from the element.

```
     let body = document.querySelector(".body");
     let bodyWidth = body.offsetWidth;
     if (bodyWidth < 785) {
        var myOpener = false;
    document.querySelector("#contact- 
    h2").setAttribute("onclick","openTheContact()");
        document.querySelector("#service- 
    h2").setAttribute("onclick","openTheServices()");
    }
     if (bodyWidth > 785) {
        document.querySelector("#contact-h2").removeAttribute("onclick");
        document.querySelector("#service-h2").removeAttribute("onclick");
     }
```

Comment: You can listen to the window size changed event - [`resize`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/resize_event). You probably will want to [debounce or throttle](http://bencentra.com/code/2015/02/27/optimizing-window-resize.html)  your check.

Comment: thank for the answer

Comment: i can't upvote you because my repo is low can you help me increase my repo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of removing and adding all the time, you may check the size after `click` event:

```
function isWindowSmall() {
    return window.innerWidth <= 785;
}

document.querySelector('#contact-h2').addEventListener('click', function () {
    if (isWindowSmall()) {
        openTheContact();
    }
});

document.querySelector('#service-h2').addEventListener('click', function () {
    if (isWindowSmall()) {
        openTheServices();
    }
});
```

Comment: well thats an easy way

Comment: and can you please upvote my question so that i can get repo and can upvote other people answers

Answer (score -1):

You should try something like this.
Using onresize event.

```
window.onresize=function(){
let body = document.querySelector(".body");
     let bodyWidth = body.offsetWidth;
     console.log("bodyWidth"+bodyWidth)
     if (bodyWidth < 785) {
        var myOpener = false;
    document.querySelector("#contact-h2").setAttribute("onclick","openTheContact()");
        document.querySelector("#service-h2").setAttribute("onclick","openTheServices()");
    }
     if (bodyWidth > 785) {
        document.querySelector("#contact-h2").removeAttribute("onclick");
        document.querySelector("#service-h2").removeAttribute("onclick");
     }
}
```